Distribution of Brownian motion conditional on linear growth
Let $W$ be a standard $d$-dimensional Brownian motion with $W_0 = 0$ almost surely.
Fix a constant $\lambda > 0$ and timeframe $T > 0$, and consider the event
$$ E_T := \{|B_s| \geq \lambda s\ \text{ for all } 0 \leq s \leq T\}.$$
Question: Can we describe the distribution of $W$ on $C[0, T]$ conditional on $E_T$?
Note that $|B_s| \sim \sqrt s$ with high probability, so this linear growth is in fact a rare event on large time frames.

The event $E_0$ has positive probability (for any fixed $T$ and $\lambda$), so it will just converge to $W$, conditioned on $E_0$. With a bit more effort one can derive a time-inhomogeneous SDE for it (with probably a reasonably nice explicit form if you send $T\to \infty$), is that what you're looking for?

@NateRiver, I guess you mean the limiting distribution at time $T$. Not later on when it's fully Brownian.

@MartinHairer Wait, I did not expect $E_0$ to have positive probability - in that case I can remove the $\varepsilon$ entirely. The SDE characterisation on $[0, T]$ sounds interesting indeed.

@ClaudeChaunier Ah yes, I am interested in the distribution on $C[0, T]$.

@Nate River Does the disintegration theorem not yield the desired conditional probability measure concentrated on the subset $E_T$ of Wiener space? Unless I am misunderstanding something it should be an exercise of checking the conditions, and at a quick glance it looks good to me.

@RobertWegner Sorry, which variable/sigma-algebra do we disintegrate with respect to?

So I thought (using Wikipedia page notatoon) consider $Y$ to be Wiener space and $X$ to be $\mathbb{R}$, both as polish spaces. Your events indicator function $\pi$ is hopefully measurable and "disintegrates" Wiener space into the preimage of 0 and preimage of 1. On both of these sets (one having full measure and one zero, I think), you now obtain new measures such that "Fubini" holds, i.e. the law of total probability in your case.

Right, this makes sense from the theoretical viewpoint, but i don’t see any way to describe the resulting probability measure on the preimage of $1$ just from the disintegration machinery. @RobertWegner

@Nate River oh I see you don't just want to construct it, you want to understand and calculate with it, maybe something like the elegant construction of the Brownian bridge.

Indeed, some sort of characterisation. (am aware that this is somewhat open ended) @RobertWegner

Your conditioned process should be a 3d Bessel process with drift $\lambda$. (Assuming you'd start with $W_0 >0$.)

@David Very interesting. I don’t mind the simplifying assumption $|W_0| = \varepsilon$.

@David Why 3D and what do you mean exactly by Bessel process with drift? It’s certainly ‘something like that’…

@MartinHairer: If I were to guess what David was willing to say is that the radial part of the conditioned process will behave roughly as $Z_t + \lambda t$, where $Z_t$ is the 3-d Bessel process. This is a reasonable approximation as long as $t$ is not too close to $0$ and $|B_t|$ is not too far away from the boundary $\lambda t$. In dimension $d = 1$, by a straightforward calculation, $|B_t| = Z_t + \lambda t$, where $dZ_t = dW_t + \lambda \coth(\lambda Z_t) dt$, and $\lambda \coth(\lambda x) \sim \frac{1}{x}$ as $x \to 0^+$. That said, I do not think there is an equally simple description…

…when $d \geqslant 2$: the radial part $|B_t|$ can be then described as follows. Let $Y_t$ be the $d$-dimensional Bessel process $Y_t$, consider $Y_t - \lambda t$, and condition this process to never go below $0$. Call this conditional process $Z_t$. Then $|B_t| = Z_t + \lambda t$. But $Y_t - \lambda t$ is no longer time-homogeneous when $d \geqslant 2$, and so I am skeptical about explicit formulae. (In both comments I mean the limiting case as $T \to \infty$, should have mentioned this earlier.)

@MateuszKwaśnicki I think the drift should be $\lambda(\coth(\lambda Z_t)-1)$ rather than $\lambda\coth(\lambda Z_t)$ in $d=1$ but otherwise I agree. My point was just that while that process is indeed something like "Bessel-3 with drift" it definitely isn't any of the naïve guesses for what this actually means...

@MartinHairer: That's not really relevant for the question, but, somewhat counterintuitively, the drift term has no “$-1$” in it. I never really trust my own calculations, so I double checked it in Williams's Path Decomposition…, https://doi.org/10.1112/plms/s3-28.4.738 (see page 744).

@NateRiver I might be wrong, but after doing Brownian scaling, this seems to be related to a Brownian meander e.g. see here https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.02350 "SOME RESULTS ON THE BROWNIAN MEANDER WITH DRIFT" where $v=\lambda$ and take $x_{0}>0$ so that we just have
$$\min_{s} B_{s}>\lambda.$$
For general techniques on conditioning on open sets, you can also see here "Brownian motion conditioned to stay in a cone".

Oh nice, so it has been looked at before. Will check it out, thanks!  @ThomasKojar
